# iOS Print pdf with URL scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I want to print a pdf file, I have already use **airPrint** but my printer is not supported.
My question is : An application like **Hp eprint** support the **url scheme**? I want to use a **third party Application** to print my pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply let UIDocumentController do it for me:

```
self.documentController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
self.documentController.delegate = self;
self.documentController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
[self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Of course Hp e-print or an other third application must be installed.